# Storing the details in list and then on inspecting storing in different list

Tags: java

I have a pojo like this..

```
public class abcObject {
    private long id;
    private long version;
    private DateTime created ;
    private String status;
}
```

and its corresponding hbm as internally it data is being stored in the table through hibernate now please advise as the status can have values like pass or failNow i have to filter the value whether it is pass or fail as rite now i can check its value by inspecting and depending upon that I have to put them into the seprate list, I have done through this way

```
List<abcObject> successful = new ArrayList <abcObject>();
List<abcObject> exception = new ArrayList <abcObject>();
List<abcObject> failure = new ArrayList <abcObject>();

//getting the list from the database into the parameter allabcObjects
List<abcdObject> allabcObjects = abcHome.getabcObjects(fileIdentifier);

if (abcObjects !=null && abcObjects.size() > 0) {
    for (abcObject f : allabcObjects) {
    }
```

Now please advise as I am using the for loop to iterate over each object then how by inspecting that is f.getstatus() method and if it is fail then it should stote all the details in fail list and if it it is success then it should store in successful list , please advise how to achieve this

Comment: You can also use Criteria API to get only list of objects meeting a certain value for status parameter. That way, you don't have to check the status in for loop, since the query itself will return the list of Objects matching certain criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare object with your strings

```
List<abcObject> successful = new ArrayList <abcObject>();
List<abcObject> exception = new ArrayList <abcObject>();
List<abcObject> failure = new ArrayList <abcObject>();


//getting the list from the database into the parameter allabcObjects
List<abcdObject> allabcObjects = abcHome.getabcObjects(fileIdentifier);

if (abcObjects !=null  && abcObjects.size()>0)
{
     for (abcObject f : allabcObjects) {

            if( "pass".equalsIgnoreCase(f.getStatus()) ) {
                successful.add( f );
            } else if ( "failNow".equalsIgnoreCase(f.getStatus()) {
                failure.add( f ); 
            }

     }
}
```

Just to point out some things. Even better would be to create `static final string`, for your success / fail string like this:

```
private static final String SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String FAIL = "failNow";
....
if( SUCCESS.equalsIgnoreCase(f.getStatus()) ) {
    successful.add( f );
} else if ( FAIL.equalsIgnoreCase(f.getStatus()) {
    failure.add( f ); 
}
```

Comparing `SUCCESS` with `f.getStatus()`, instead of inverse, gives us certainty that there won't be NullPointerException if somehow `f` would be null

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop would read:

```
for (abcObject f : allabcObjects) {
    String status = f.getstatus();
    if(status.equals("fail")){
        failure.add(f);
    }
    else{
        otherList.add(f);
    }
}
```

You'll also need to declare the `otherList`, i.e.

```
List<abcObject> otherList = new ArrayList<abcObject>();
```

This assumes that your getstatus() method returns a String "fail" if it fails.

Comment: Objects, like String, should be compared with `.equals()` not `==`

Comment: yep I was originally creating it as a `MyStatusObject` then changed it to a String for clarity - too quickly obviously, my bad. Fixed now.